# MS Access Form to Query with Date Ranges (And Even Without)

Tags: ms-access

I'm new to Access and I'm building a database here at work to log all production that was done. I was able to make a query form with criteria between a date range, condition, part number and work order. Using a code in the expression builder, these are what is placed in the criterion:

Date range: `Between [Forms]![Form Query]![BeginDate] And [Forms]![Form Query]![EndDate]`

Part number: `Like (IIf(IsNull([Forms]![Form Query]![Part Number]),"*",[Forms]![Form Query]![Part Number]))`

Condition: `Like (IIf(IsNull([Forms]![Form Query]![Condition]),"*",[Forms]![Form Query]![Condition]))`

This is where even when part numbers and condition is empty, the query will display all records. My problem is the date range if I leave it empty (say, I simply wanted to query all of the records), it will return with zero value. I wanted it to make it simple for the user that if I leave the date range empty, it will still show *all* of the records. I had to temporarily put the date range as required to always return results.

[Query form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHNcn.png)

[Query Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ4Sw.png)

All input is appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: That is why I prefer VBA to construct filter criteria and apply to form or report http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide alternate value if date is not input:

`Between Nz([Forms]![Form Query]![BeginDate], #1/1/1900#) And Nz([Forms]![Form Query]![EndDate], #12/31/2200#)`

For text fields, assuming value is unique and is never part of a longer string, LIKE criteria can just concatenate wildcard:

`LIKE [Forms]![Form Query]![Part Number]) & "*"`

Comment: Thank you sir! The form worked perfectly as I wanted to.